# Default RealityKit application isn't working

Tags: ios, xcode, augmented-reality, realitykit

When running the generated Augmented Reality app with RealityKit from Xcode, nothing appears on the screen and I'm getting weird logs on the console:

```
2020-09-16 16:54:29.246883+0200 TestAR[494:29654] Metal GPU Frame Capture Enabled 
2020-09-16 16:54:29.247203+0200 TestAR[494:29654] Metal API Validation Enabled
2020-09-16 16:54:29.792709+0200 TestAR[494:29654] Compiler failed to build request
2020-09-16 16:54:29.792957+0200 TestAR[494:29654] [Graphics] makeRenderPipelineState failed [output of type ushort is not compatible with a MTLPixelFormatR16Float color attachement.].
2020-09-16 16:54:29.792989+0200 TestAR[494:29654] [Graphics] makeRenderPipelineState failed.
```

I have tried to run the app on my two devices and the result is the same. Also tried to use Xcode 12, same result. What's even more disturbing is that I got the app to work like 2 times on the 20+ tries at random without changing anything, just killing the app and restarting or closing xcode and restaring.

Here is the code, but this is just the basic generated code:

```swift
struct ContentView : View {
    var body: some View {
        return ARViewContainer().edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
    }
}

struct ARViewContainer: UIViewRepresentable {
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> ARView {       
        let arView = ARView(frame: .zero)
        let boxAnchor = try! Experience.loadBox()
        arView.scene.anchors.append(boxAnchor)
        return arView       
    } 
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: ARView, context: Context) {}
}
```

At this point I don't really understand what I'm doing wrong, here are the additionnal informations:

- macOS Catalina v10.15.5
- iPhone X 13.5.1
- iPhone X 13.7
- iPhone 6S Plus 13.5.1
- Xcode 11.7
- Xcode 12

Answer (score 0):

At first you have to make sure that you didn't change a content in `AppDelegate.swift` file. A window's root view controller must come from `contentView`:

```
let contentView = ContentView()
window.rootViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: contentView)
window.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

**Solution I**

Sometimes in Xcode you may observe a bug – your app can't be launched or run due to some errors found in intermediate compiled data folder. All you need to do is to empty a `DerivedData` directory.

For that in Finder just press a shortcut <kbd>Cmd</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>G</kbd> and specify the following path to get to desired directory:

```
~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/
```

After the deletion of a content of `DerivedData` directory your compiled app must be working as expected.

Additional info about [DerivedData](https://mgrebenets.github.io/mobile%20ci/2015/02/01/xcode-derived-data):

> `DerivedData` is a folder located in `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData` by default. It’s the location where Xcode stores all kinds of intermediate build results, generated indexes, etc. DerivedData location can be configured in Xcode preferences (Locations tab).

**Solution II**

If the above two steps didn't help, you should reinstall Xcode.